# Don't match if there is an extra period at the end of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex:

```
\n\n|(?<=[^,][."*?!\^])(?!\.)[ ](?=["*]?[A-Z])
```

To match the empty space after a sentence (I'm using `[ ]` to show you the matches):

```
First sentence.[ ]Middle a sentence..[ ]Last sentence.

First sentence?[ ]Middle a sentence!.[ ]Last sentence.

"First sentence," Middle a sentence..[ ]Last sentence.

"First sentence."[ ]"Middle a sentence.".[ ]Last sentence.
```

It's worked fine so far. But now I want the regex not to match when there are `..`, `?.`, `!.`, `.".`, etc. at the end of a sentence. In other words, when there's an extra period:

```
First sentence.[ ]Middle a sentence.. Last sentence.

First sentence?[ ]Middle a sentence!. Last sentence.

"First sentence," Middle a sentence.. Last sentence.

"First sentence."[ ]"Middle a sentence.". Last sentence.
```

I thought adding an `(?!\.)` would do the trick:

```
\n\n|(?<=[^,][."*?!\^])(?!\.)[ ](?=["*]?[A-Z])
```

But as you can see [here](https://regexr.com/6fqog), it's still matching the empty spaces after the extra period.

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: As I understand, `.".` is not to be matched. Are `."` and `".` to be matched? Why are the periods at the end of each line not matched? Inserting `[ ]` to identify matches is a bit of a nuisance for readers who want to test against your data. Better, imo, would be to put, say, a caret, `^`, under matches.

Comment: If I understand the requirements correctly you can match against the regular expression `/(?<![.!?])(?<!\.")\.(?!(?:\.)|"\.)/`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbJIRF/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland But a match is a region. Start and end. I don't think I can show that with a caret?

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you mean by a "region"; that is, I don't understand what the `[ ]`'s are referring to. I'm off to bed so won't be able to comment more until 1 sleep cycle has been completed.

Comment: Maybe you need `/\n\n|(?<=[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}][.*"?!^]|"(?=\s+"[A-Z]))\s+(?=["*]?\p{Lu})/gu`? This is fully Unicode aware regex. See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/9J9fqv/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend this negated class `[^,]` with all other characters that you don't want to occur as one-before-last character in a sentence.

So like: `[^,.]`

If however you want to allow `."` to end a sentence, and only want to avoid two points (or `!.` and `".`), then put your look around condition there as look-back:

`(?<=[^,][."*?!\^])(?<![.!?"]\.)`

Comment: But I think that isn't going to match `?.`, `!.` and so on? And `."` isn't going to match anymore?

Comment: Added more to my answer. If you need a more specific answer, then please provide an exhaustive list of what is allowed and what is not. But with the combination of a positive and negative look-behind you can detail exactly what you want for those 2 last characters.

Comment: This did it: `(?<=[^,][."*?!\^])(?<![."*?!\^]\.)`. Thanks, I'll accept your answer if there isn't another better one.